# Are there English dubbed anime on Crunchyroll?

Tags: crunchyroll

It's of course understood that not all anime have been, nor will be dubbed.

Anyway, are there any English dubbed anime on Crunchyroll? If there are, is there a setting for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Crunchyroll has a small number of shows with English dubs. These are listed on their forums [here](http://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-788825/crs-english-dubbed-anime). I could not find a way to search for them, so I have no way of knowing if the list is complete or not, but in any event there probably aren't a lot more than what is listed there. There have been others in the past, but never a huge number. CR is still primarily concerned with subtitled anime, which are typically cheaper and more abundant.

There are some other legal streaming sites which have larger collections of dubbed anime. What's available tends to vary significantly from country to country. In North America the biggest sources for legal dub streams are probably [The Anime Network](http://www.theanimenetwork.com/) and [Funimation](http://www.funimation.com/). I unfortunately don't know whether these are available to the rest of the world or what the popular alternatives are in other places.

Comment: Funimation and The Anime Network aren't available in Ireland (and probably all of Europe) anyway, there aren't many alternatives either :(

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko These kind of streaming sites operate on US licensing. This kind of licensing is easier to obtain from the copyright holder and does not need to adhere to foreign rules. The European Union is working on governing laws that would allow licensing for the entire EU in one go. When, or if, that happens, more streaming sites will be able to reach the EU with relative ease. For now, there is no alternative for us (Other than, of course, the *less legal* methods of acquisition).